# Is there a simple(r) way to copy all data from a premium storage account to an archive storage account in Azure? Using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to move my containers, directories, and files under each container over to our archive account, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to move data over.

I built a SQL table which holds all the container names, so that I could reference it in a copy data activity, but it doesn't seem like the most efficient method of copying data over.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: What's the strategy behind moving, and not just using lifecycle policies?

Answer (score 0):

- Try creating the source dataset for the datalake storage (not pointing to any container)
- Inside Copy activity, use wildcard filepath and give * as the file pattern
  Check 'recursively' option
- Point the sink dataset to another ADLS account again without pointing to any specific container.